# Send email with confirmation link in Google Forms?

Tags: google-forms

Is there a way to have Google Forms send a confirmation email, containing a unique link that the user must click in order to validate the form? If the user does not click the link, the form is not accepted.

If it is simpler, I could also send a code to the user by email, which the user must input in the form.

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: @peshkira No, sorry

Comment: Thanks for answering